# R: How to transform long longitudinal data to wide longitudinal data, when I only have the age (in days) as an indicator of measurement time?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, longitudinal, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I have a long-formatted set of longitudinal data with two variables that change over time (`cognitive_score` and `motor_score`), subject id (labeled `subjid`) and age of each subject in days at the moment of measurement(labeled `agedays`). Measurements were taken twice.

I want to transform it to wide-formatted longitudinal dataset.

The problem is that `agedays` measurements are unique for each subject, and the only way to see which measurement entry was the first, and which was the second, is to check where the agedays is higher (`agedays` higher than in the other entry means second measurement, lower `agedays` means first measurement).

We thus have this dataset:

```
    subjid agedays cognitive_score motor_score
        <int>   <int>           <dbl>       <dbl>
    1 4900001     457           0.338       0.176
    2 4900001    1035           0.191       0.216
    3 4900002     639           0.25        0.176
    4 4900002    1248           0.176       0.353
    5 4900003     335           0.103       0.196
    6 4900003     913           0.176       0.196
```

And what I tried was using reshape:

```
reshape(dataset_col, direction = "wide", idvar = "subjid", timevar = "agedays", v.names = c("cognitive_score", "motor_score"))
```

Where `dataset_col` is the name of the dataset.

What it does, however, is adding these two columns:

[image: result of the above-listed command execution]

The numbers in the name of the columns seem to be the values of `agedays` variable.

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Did you try tidyverse `group_by`?

Answer (score 0):

With libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

You can use `group_by` and `mutate` to determine which of the ids is the first measurement and which is the second measurement.  In this case I used an `ifelse` statement to determine which measurement is the first, this only works if you have exactly 2 measurements for each subjid.

Then you can use `pivot_wider` to pivot your data to wide format based on your newly created names column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(subjid) %>%
  mutate(names = ifelse(agedays == min(agedays),"first","second")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = c(agedays,cognitive_score,motor_score))

# A tibble: 3 × 7
# Groups:   subjid [3]
#   subjid agedays_first agedays_second cognitive_score_first cognitive_score_second motor_score_first motor_score_second
#    <int>         <int>          <int>                 <dbl>                  <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>
# 1 4900001           457           1035                 0.338                  0.191             0.176              0.216
# 2 4900002           639           1248                 0.25                   0.176             0.176              0.353
# 3 4900003           335            913                 0.103                  0.176             0.196              0.196
```